Change of country in US visa portal
I am an Indian citizen but currently living in Germany with a long-term research visa (D Type). Now, I have an opportunity from the US, and I need to apply for a J1 (DS-2019 is already approved and sent to me by the university), but in the CGI portal I can't see the option for Germany, and when the option is "from where you want to apply for the visa", it automatically shows India. I already emailed support-germany@ustraveldocs.com to transfer my country from India to Germany, but they did not respond.
As I am working and living in Germany, I need to apply for a visa from Germany. I also tried to contact the USTravelDocs customer services in Germany through call and live chat but the chat or call couldn't connect. As my joining date is 13/05/2024, I desperately want to transfer the country to my CGI USTravelDocs portal.
